# Histogram of circular area

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I got an image and I have a certain area on that image from which I want to get a grayscale histogram.
In more detail: I have an image with bounding boxes on them and I want to put a circle into that bounding box and calculate a grayscale histogram of that circle inside that bounding box.

I already got the circle working, but how can I calculate the grayscale histogram?

This is what I got:

Circle on image:

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind that a histogram is independent of the shape, or layout of the original image. A sheet of paper where the top half is black and the bottom half white has the same histogram as a chess-board. So, if you can find the pixels, it doesn't matter if they are in a circle or all arranged into a tall column vector, 1 pixel wide.

Comment: Thank you for that reminder. Yes you're right, it's just that I only want to include the pixels from that circle into my histogram and not all pixels from the picture. I'm wondering how that could be done

Comment: See cv2.calcHist(). It permits a mask to be specified to limit where the histogram is produces. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d

Comment: Okay thank you for that link! I'm just still confused about the mask. How would I create the mask for the circle. I know how to draw the circle on the picture. I guess it's just a little modification of the code.
As soon as I got the mask right, it's just using the cv2.calcHist() function and I would be done.